# KDB: how do I insert/upsert rows from one table to another

Tags: kdb

```
k1:([a:("ff"; "yy"; "zz");z:("tt"; "yy"; "hh")] b:("33"; "44"; "55"); c:("66"; "77"; "88"))


k2:([z:()] a:(); b:(); c:(); m:(); i:())
```

`k1` and `k2` are keyed tables. `k2` has all the columns of `k1` and more.

How do I perform a conditional upsert from `k1` to `k2`. Basically, what is the corresponding working statement of the one below:

```
`k2 upsert select k1 where a="ff"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this will solve your issue:

```
k2 uj `z xkey select from k1 where a like "ff"
```

the xkey will maintain the key on k2 while the uj will maintain all of the columns, including those without values in k1.

In this example this would return:

```
z   | a    b    c    m i
----| ------------------
"tt"| "ff" "33" "66"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your attempted statement is actually very close. You can use:

```
`k2 upsert 0!select from k1 where a like "ff"
```